# Are State Plane Coordinates always derived from longitude and latitude?

Tags: coordinate-system, state-plane

Do state plane coordinates *always* begin as longitude and latitude?

In other words, they are not another system that can be calculated without Long. and Lat., correct?

I guess I'm saying, back in 1930+ they came up with the State Plane system.  To make that work, however, they had to start with L&L.  Today, I am guessing I can simply compare it to a database.  But if for example, I have a GPS device and I want to know the Plane Coordinate, I have to convert it.

Comment: If you are asking a historical question, [this](http://archives.profsurv.com/magazine/article.aspx?i=1180) article may be interesting to you.

Answer (score 4):

Almost all software for doing coordinate projection use geographic coordinates as a standard system in the middle and defines "forward" (from geographic to projected) and "inverse" (from projected to geographic) routines for projections.

So, to go from a UTM projection (say "UTM 10 N") to a stateplane projection (say "Washington Stateplane North") you'd first run the inverse projection from UTM to geographic, then run the forward projection from geographic to stateplane.

Answer (score 1):

There are algorithms that will transform from a grid system to another grid system without going without requiring a conversion to lat-long.  So the best answer I can come up with is not always, but often they use lat-long.